# Suppose we have a list of 3-letter words with 3 elements, but each word is also a list. The function return the character at the given index

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we have a list of 3-letter words with 3 elements, but each word is also a list. See example below:

word_list = [  ['r','e','d'] , ['p','e','a'] , ['z','i','p']  ]

Create a function named getCharacterAt that accepts 2 arguments - word_list and index_of_character. The function should be able to return the character at the given index. (If index_of_character is 3, we get 3rd letter in the whole list which is 'd'. If it is 5, we get 'e'. If 9, we get 'p'.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list = [ ['r','e','d'] , ['p','e','a'] , ['z','i','p'] ]

new_word_list = []
for i in word_list:

    new_word_list = new_word_list + i


def getCharacterAt(word_list: list, index_of_character: int):

    return word_list[index_of_character - 1]


print(getCharacterAt(new_word_list, 3))
# Output: d
```

In this case, I have created a 'new_word_list' with the union of each element of 'word_list'. Then, following your description, you just return the index - 1 element of the request (remember that first list index is 0)